# redirect subdomain within IIS7.5 using https

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I have setup wildcard on an IIS 7.5 site. I am now trying to force all users to 
e.g. [https://store1.mydomain.com or https://store2.mydomain.com](https://storename1.mydomain.com)

I have only been able to find examples for redirecting to www.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Based on what should the decision be made to redirect the users to store1 or store2?  What are (some of) the possible domain names the users use to initially access the site?

Comment: Hey Marco, I have a wildcard setup so they could be anything. Currently the site is working under SSL with the wild card however I want to force users to use https and dont display the 405 page

Comment: I forogt to mention im using mvc3. mvc makes it super easy to redirect everything to ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL rewrite module to force the user to switch to SSL, regardless of the host name or the URL the users uses to enter the site. Use the following rule:

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" negate="true" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Hope this is what you need.